# Special Android 3D engine

Tags: android, view, 3d, fragment

I'm looking for a good 3D rendering and animation engine for Android, what can be migrated into the new 3.x Fragments views - as I want it to be a simple View, not a whole-UI screen. What engine can do this easily? My needed features would be simple animations (rotation), lighting, material change.

Comment: there is a list of 3D Android Game Engines that you might find useful http://mobilegameengines.com/android/3d_game_engines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's hard to say what will be future proof in terms supporting upcoming features such as 3.x Fragment Views. But that being said, we've been taking a look recently at RightWare Kanzi for a different approach for handling our rendering and animation on Android.  Take a look at their website and product sheets for their product offering that consists of [Kanzi](http://www.rightware.com/en/Kanzi+UI+Solution/), [Kanzi Studio](http://www.rightware.com/en/Kanzi+UI+Solution/Kanzi+Studio/) and the Kanzi Engine. At the very least, I know they can accommodate rotation, lighting and material changes.

Comment: Yes, I know Kanzi, but it isn't so great in my view. It's price is high, and I don't want to buy a software for hundreds (or thousands) of dollars for a simple home project of mine, as this app I'm writing is going to be freeware.

Comment: Ah, never mind, found something more interesting, called Min3D. Pure Java library, supports formats and animations, multi-materials, lighting, everything. Free, and works with the Android Views perfectly :D

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest jMonkey, a big advantage is that you can run it on Desktop+Android, so development is more comfortable